# Ubuntu 12.04 package dependency

Tags: dependencies, package, ubuntu-12.04, apt-get

I have following problem

```
:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6 : Depends: libc-bin (= 2.15-0ubuntu10.3)
 libc6:i386 : Depends: libc-bin:i386 (= 2.15-0ubuntu10.3)
 libc6-dbg : Depends: libc6 (= 2.15-0ubuntu10.4) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.3 is installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.15-0ubuntu10.4) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.3 is installed
             Depends: libc-dev-bin (= 2.15-0ubuntu10.4)
 libc6-dev:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (= 2.15-0ubuntu10.4) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.3 is installed
                  Depends: libc-dev-bin:i386 (= 2.15-0ubuntu10.4)
                  Recommends: gcc:i386 but it is not installed or
                              c-compiler:i386
 libc6-i386 : Depends: libc6 (= 2.15-0ubuntu10.4) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.3 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

I try many methods, but I do not know how to deal.

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem for ubuntu sdk install, but generally the problem comes from the PPAs you have installed as third party. You can try unchecking them and update againg than try again what u want to do. (from software center PPAs).

my gratitudes..